# How do I limit the number of emails downloaded in Apple Mail for iOS 16?

Tags: iphone, icloud, mail.app, email, gmail

After several years with an Android phone, I have an iPhone again.

I have a few Gmail accounts, as well as an iCloud account (from years ago).

I connected one Gmail account, and the iCloud account is connected automatically.

However, immediately the Apple Mail app started downloading *thousands* of emails. It seems to have downloaded the entire iCloud mail history, as well as *all* the Gmail emails. In addition, it loaded thousands of Gmail emails into "spam", even though they weren't marked as spam before. I tried to move all of the Gmail emails from spam to the Inbox, which means, of course, that I may have moved some actual spam emails to. But today when I go to my Gmail inbox, I have no emails for the last year -- they are there, in "All Mail", but not in "Inbox" nor in "Spam".

Understandably I'm a bit frustrated. Not sure where things are going wrong, but any help would be appreciated.

To start, I'd really appreciate being able to limit the emails in my iPhone to a reasonable limit -- the last month, for example. Is there any way to do this? I was told to look for "days to sync", but I cannot find this for iCloud or Gmail email accounts -- I click on account settings, and don't see anything. The phone is running iOS 16, so I don't know if they've moved it/removed it.

If I find a way to limit the number of emails downloaded, what do I need to do to remove the thousands already downloaded? Do I need to remove the Gmail account and add it again? And for the iCloud account? (If I just delete the emails on my iPhone, unfortunately they'll be deleted everywhere, which isn't what I want).

Comment: When you say 'messages' are you referring to Apple Mail (email) or Messages (text messages)?  I'm a little confused because the title states Mail but the body states messages.

Comment: Sorry, I meant emails -- I edited the original post to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

I think the 'Mail Days to Sync' setting is only available for Exchange accounts such as M365. IMAP accounts such as iCloud and Gmail don't have this option.

Comment: I’ve confirmed that  Exchange and Outlook.com have the ability to select an amount if time to sync mail.  GMail and Yahoo! Do not have this option.